# Set Time from one ViewController to one ViewController

Tags: ios

My App crashed because  I set time from one ViewController to one ViewController in AppDelegate.m for method below and it show the message : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a0e360.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self performSelector:@selector(toSecondViewController:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

-(void)toSecondViewController{
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sale animated:YES];
}
```

I don't know why ?

Comment: If you don't include an error message and stack trace we probably don't know why either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change code

```
[self performSelector:@selector(toSecondViewController:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

to

```
[self performSelector:@selector(toSecondViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

If func is not have any parameter, then don't add "**:**" symbol after func name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send any parameter then only you should add ":". Otherwise there is no need to add.

So the correct code is-
[self performSelector:@selector(toSecondViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];